# Remove filed after populating model attributes

Tags: yii

I messed up with this problem:

In my controller action, I alreadly populated a special model attribute (for example project_id attribute as shown below) with one value:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Issue;

    $model->project_id = $this->_project->id;
    if(isset($_POST['Issue']))
    ......
```

Then why in _form.php for the above create action we have to use hiddenField for this attribute:

```
<?php echo $form->hiddenField($model,'project_id'); ?>
```

Why not remove them compeletely?

Answer (score 0):

If you assign manually in your `actionCreate` an attribute to the model, along from the ones collected from `$_POST`, then there is no need to render a hidden field for that attribute in the form.

Anyway, a lot of times it's better to do that kind of logic in the model itself, for example in the [`beforeSave()` method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord/#beforeSave-detail), because most of the times this is model logic and not controller logic. If the model were used in other controller, then you should repeat the attribute assignment again, but if it is in the model then you can keep your code DRY.

Comment: Thank for your answer, however, I just followed the step in a book called "Agile web application development with Yii".  I just wondering why the author already assign a value to a attribute of a AR Class instance, and then, he still leave the input form view (form.php) with "hiddenField" for this value. I mean, why not completely remove them, because, we have alreadly added it to the instance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

However, my question is mainly focus on: could I just remove field after I have populated into the model, or will I have to stick with hidden field, is this a "security issue" that if I completely remove it the logic will be break somewhere (in fact, when I remove it I see no error). 

But till I am not supper at Yii, I really need your help for my vague thought.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it is exactly as I wrote here. And maybe to be more clearly, this code DOES NOT assigns ID, it assigns PROJECT_ID to Issue Model. Its id is automotically added as you said .